# Finding mean of timestamp data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, timestamp, mean

I have a data of time (in char) in which a particular event occurs and I want to find the mean of the time. For e.g.,

```
a = ['8:00 am'; '8:10 am'; '8:20 am'; '8:30 am'];
```

The output should be 8:15 am. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with the solution.

```
a = ['8:00 am'; '8:10 am'; '8:20 am'; '8:30 am'];
b = datestr(mean(datenum(a)), 'HH:MM PM');
```